# "query has no destination for result data" in PL/PgSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I need to show the Tree_Nodes table data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample()
      RETURNS TABLE() AS
    $BODY$ 

    BEGIN
        select * from "Tree_Nodes";
    END;
    $BODY$

      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100
      ROWS 1000;
    ALTER FUNCTION sample()
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

It fails with:

```
 ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
```

Avoid the error and i will get the table column format in all data

Answer (score 3):

To return the result of a SELECT, a pure SQL function is much more suitable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample()
  RETURNS TABLE ( .... ) AS
$BODY$ 
  select * from "Tree_Nodes";
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Or if you really need PL/pgSQL, you need to use `return query` (which is clearly documented in the manual)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample()
      RETURNS TABLE (....) 
AS
$BODY$ 
BEGIN
   return query select * from "Tree_Nodes";
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But you cannot just specify `returns table()` you have to also define the structure of the result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample()
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, some_column text, other_column decimal(10,2), ...) 
AS
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact error you quote is caused by using `SELECT` without an `INTO` clause in PL/PgSQL. You must either use `SELECT INTO somevariable`, use `RETURN QUERY`, if you want to discard the data, use the `PERFORM` statement instead of `SELECT`, [as covered by the PL/PgSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html).

Once you fix that by using `RETURN QUERY SELECT ....` you'll find that the function still doesn't work, because `RETURNS TABLE()` doesn't make sense. You're returning an empty result set. It'll fail, complaining that the statement is returning a result set that doesn't match the function.

It makes no sense to do this anyway, since you can just write it as a trivial SQL function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample()
      RETURNS SETOF "Tree_Nodes"
AS $$
    SELECT * FROM "Tree_Nodes";
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This function appears to serve no purpose. What are you trying to achieve with it?

(By the way, you should generally avoid `SELECT *` in production code. List the columns. That way, if you add a column later, things that use the table won't suddenly stop working.)

Comment: Hi Craig Ringer, (select * from "Tree_Nodes"); can you tel me which place i will change...

Comment: @Kannan I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: +1, I just learned something new: `return setof "Tree_nodes"`. I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yup, every table creates an implicit type. It's occasionally quite handy, though it can get a bit "interesting" with dropped columns, etc, so it's something I'd usually only do in a situation like this where the exact columns aren't known.